# Porque con el split me mete una coma ¿?

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas intento agarrar la "src" de una imagen con jquery del cual esta codificada y quiero quitarle los puntos y barras.

He intentado esto, tengo esta imagen:

```
<img id="4" src="./uploads/b806973186f816a6a0e35038f4e8ef97329ff6fcbb31cc30412b5a76c7a4e274" class="gallery-image mostr_img">
```

Del cual quiero obtener esto:

> b806973186f816a6a0e35038f4e8ef97329ff6fcbb31cc30412b5a76c7a4e274

Con jquery hago esto :

```
var urlPath = $(".mostr_img").attr("src").split("./uploads/");
console.log(urlPath);
alert(urlPath);
```

Y me devuelve esto:

> ,b806973186f816a6a0e35038f4e8ef97329ff6fcbb31cc30412b5a76c7a4e274

Pero en todas las imagenes me quita bien las barras,punto y el upload, pero luego me añade una "," en todo lo que me devuelve. Porque ?

Comment: Es raro y creo que lo estás leyendo mal. Según entiendo, el método split, lo que hace es dividir un string en un array de acuerdo a lo que le pases como separador. Creo que lo que estás viendo es el separador de tu array. Creo que si haces `console.log(urlPath[1])`, debería mostrarte tu string sin problemas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si te das cuenta, hay un elemento vacío

```js
console.log("./uploads/b806973186f816a6a0e35038f4e8ef97329ff6fcbb31cc30412b5a76c7a4e274".split("./uploads/"))
```

Entonces, al unir el array que se forma a través de `split`, se toma en cuenta el elemento vacío y la coma para separarlo al otro elemento

**Usar [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)**

El error que tienes es usar `join` así: `join()`, cuando debería ser así `join("")`

```js
console.log("./uploads/b806973186f816a6a0e35038f4e8ef97329ff6fcbb31cc30412b5a76c7a4e274".split("./uploads/").join(""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es lo siguiente: el método `String.split` devuelve un **array de strings**, no un string. En este caso devuelve lo siguiente:

```
[
  "",
  "b806973186f816a6a0e35038f4e8ef97329ff6fcbb31cc30412b5a76c7a4e274"
]
```

Es decir, usando como separador `"./uploads/"`, has dividido el string original en 2, lo que hay antes (nada, por tanto un string vacío) y lo que hay después (ese valor hexadecimal).
Y, cuando intentas mostrar este array en consola o con un alert, se intenta transformas en un único string, concatenando cada elemento del array con una coma entre cada dos elementos. Como el primer elemento es un string vacío, lo que ves es una coma y el segundo elemento:

```js
const url = "./uploads/b806973186f816a6a0e35038f4e8ef97329ff6fcbb31cc30412b5a76c7a4e274";

const result = url.split("./uploads/");

console.log("Como array:", JSON.stringify(result));
console.log("Como string:", result.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Siendo que `split()` devuelve un array, para este caso podrías usar también [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) para obtener la última parte, que es el dato que te interesa.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const url = "./uploads/b806973186f816a6a0e35038f4e8ef97329ff6fcbb31cc30412b5a76c7a4e274";

const result = url.split("./uploads/").pop();
console.log(result);
```

Otra posibilidad sería remover la parte que no te interesa de la cadena con [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
let result = "./uploads/b806973186f816a6a0e35038f4e8ef97329ff6fcbb31cc30412b5a76c7a4e274".replace("./uploads/","");

console.log(result);
```